# How can I make a text take a fixed width based on the length of a string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget tree as follows:

```dart
Widget example() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
            Text('25.00%')
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
            Text('125.00%')
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
            Text('1250.00%')
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

How can I make all texts take the same horizontal space without using pixels in width so that all containers are aligned vertically?

I would like to set a fixed length for my percentages and the ones that are shorter are padded with spaces and the ones that are longer get cropped with the text elipsis.

Is there a clean build in method to do that?

Comment: If you are willing to fixed width for your percentages, why not fixed pixel width then?

Answer (score 2):

Since your requirement is to set a fixed width for the percentages and ellipsize the text if it overflows, I'll suggest that you wrap your `Text` widget too inside an `Expanded` widget and use `flex` property for both the expanded components of the row. I'm suggesting a ratio of 5:1 between both components of the row, represented by `flex1` and `flex2` respectively. However, you may set the flex as per your requirement.
Secondly, I've used `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` in all of the `Text` widgets that will take care of the ellipsis part of your requirement.
I've also aligned the text to right but that's totally up to u.

Following is the revised code:

```
Widget example2() {
  int flex1 = 5;
  int flex2 = 1;
  return Column(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: flex1,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: flex2,
            child: const Text('25.00%',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: flex1,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: flex2,
            child: const Text('125.00%',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: flex1,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: flex2,
            child: const Text(
              '1250.00%',
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you this did the trick, although I'm not sure if it is exactly the solution. I'm still far from having a deep knowledge of mobile development, but I could guess this solution may not work if the user has some scaling in the text (i.e. older people)?

Comment: What would be your further requirement if there is a scaling in the text?

Comment: Preserve the length of the text reducing the size of the container when the text is bigger. So always the text has the same length.

Answer (score 0):

the solution for all those issues is in the [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package, you can set a `maxLines` to set the maximum lines an `AutoSizeText` so if you have multiple `AutoSizeText` widgets, all will take the same horizontal space because however, your text is long, the package will resize it to fit in the specific lines ranges, otherwise, you can give it ellipsis style.

```
AutoSizeText(
  yourText,
  maxLines: 1,
  minFontSize: 10,
  wrapWords: false,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
);
```

Comment: Thank you but I think this is not exactly what I'm looking for, as this seems to be just changing the font size, i'd like to have everything homogeneous but with some white space padding in case the text is too short.

Comment: is using \n to jumb to new line fits your case

Comment: Text("text \n text text text text \n text text "); like this ?